# Download a file from navbar using the "download" attribute with HashRouter (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, download, react-router-dom

I have a navbar and I want one of its elements to download a file that is in the public directory of my repo when clicking on it.
I'm using `HashRouter` from `'react-router-dom'`.

Normally we would use `Link` from `'react-router-dom'` :

```
    <Link
      key={section.name}
      to={section.link}
      download={section.link === '/myfile.txt' ? 'myfile.txt' : undefined}
    >
      {section.name}
    </Link>
```

But the download doesn't work (file not found) knowing that the file is in the public folder.

As a temporary solution to this problem, I used the `<a>` tag instead, but had to manually add `#` for the other navbar elements for navigation :

```
    <a
      key={section.name}
      href={section.link === '/myfile.txt' ? section.link : `#${section.link}`}
      download={section.link === '/myfile.txt' ? 'myfile.txt' : undefined}
    >
      {section.name}
    </a>
```

My question is how can I do it with the `Link` tag?

Comment: The `Link` component handles navigating to paths you are rendering routes for. Use raw anchor tags for anything other than navigating around your app, e.g. to external links, file downloads, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a custom link component that conditionally renders either a `Link` component or `a` element depending on the presence of any `download` prop.

Example:

```
const CustomLink = ({ children, download, to, ...props }) => {
  return download
    ? <a href={to} download={download} {...props}>{children}</a>
    : <Link to={to} {...props}>{children}</Link>;
};
```

```
<CustomLink
  key={section.name}
  to={section.link}
  download={section.download}
>
  {section.name}
</CustomLink>
```